# Video Rate (like/dislike/none) using google-api-php-client

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm developing a script for rating a video using google-api-php-client. When it executes, Google API responses to me: **{"data", null}** and nothing else happens.

So, I dont know if my code is wrong. Here, there is a example of use Google_Service_Youtube to rate a video:

```
// SCRIPT FOR RATING A YOUTUBE VIDEO
// Trying to rate for this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE8ODPL2VPI

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../autoload.php');

// API GOOGLE CLIENT PARAMS
$client_id  = 'SET_CLIENT_ID_GOOGLE_API';
$client_secret  = 'SET_CLIENT_SECRET_GOOGLE_API';
$redirect_uri   = 'SET_REDIRECT_URI_GOOGLE_API';
// ID VIDEO FOR RATING
$id_video   = 'ZE8ODPL2VPI';
$rating     = 'like'; // Acceptable values: dislike, like, none
// LOCAL SCRIPT PARAMS    
$is_auth    = false;
// REQUEST (POST|GET) PARAMS
$idvideo    = null; 
$rating     = null;
$code       = null;

if(isset($_POST["idvideo"])) $idvideo = $_POST["idvideo"];
if(isset($_POST["rating"])) $rating = $_POST["rating"];
if(isset($_GET["code"])) $code = $_GET["code"];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"); 

if(isset($_SESSION['youtube_data']) && !empty($_SESSION['youtube_data'])) 
      $is_auth = true;  
if($is_auth){

    $token = $_SESSION['youtube_data'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);

    if($idvideo != null && $rating != null){

        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
        $result = $youtube->videos->rate($idvideo,$rating);

        echo $result;

    }else{
        echo '
        <form action="rating_video.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="rating" value="'.$rating.'" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="idvideo" value="'.$id_video.'" />
            <button type="submit">I like: '.$id_video.'</button>
        </form>';
    }

}else{  

    if($code != null){      

        $client->authenticate($code);
        $_SESSION['youtube_data'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    }else{
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();            
        echo "<a href='$authUrl'>Sign in with Google </a>";     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) says:

> If successful, this method returns an HTTP 204 response code (No
>   Content).

The library will throw an exception if there's an error. Since you're not seeing any errors, this means the request was successful and the rating was saved. You can check this by going to the video page and seeing that the thumbs up icon is highlighted.